# Java Firebase server application.. works fine when I run it in IntelliJ but the .class file doesn't run

Tags: java, firebase, maven, intellij-idea, server

I wrote a little server application to run some commands on my firebase Firestore. When I run the project within IntelliJ it works like a charm. So I want to send the .class files to my server now to run it on there but for some reason I can't run it, neither on the machine I am programming on nor the server.

"java MyFirebaseServer" in console gives me following error:

Error: Unable to initialize main class MyFirebaseServer
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials

I used maven for this project and iam not familiar with that, maybe I just don't get that part.

Here is the code of the ServerClass, I stripped it down to minimum, just enough so the error is reproduced:

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MyFirebaseServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("HelloWorld");

        FileInputStream serviceAccount =
                null;
        try {
            serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("/Users/myserviceaccountfile.json");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        FirebaseOptions options;
        options = null;
        try {
            options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("here goes my db url")
                    .build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Now comes the pom , it probably is a total mess as I have not much knowledge about maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyFirebaseServer</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>MyFirebaseServer</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
      <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
      <version>6.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-firestore</artifactId>
      <version>1.32.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
      <artifactId>firebase-server-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>MyFirebaseServer</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Did anybody have similar issues or any idea where I go wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I ended up using Gradle for dependencies instead and build the project as "FatJar".. Hope thats helpful for you.